# How do we know the space of distributions is "big"?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dual-spaces

Consider the set of compactly supported smooth functions $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$. The dual of this space, $(C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}))'$ is often referred to as a very large space. Since every $f \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ can be mapped to an element in the dual space by integration we know that $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}) \subset (C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}))'$ and that this inclusion is strict since non-regular distributions are known to exist.

But how do we know that the dual space is much larger than the original space? That is, how do we know the non-regular distributions are not rare? Is there a way to quantify how much bigger the dual space is compared to the original space?

Comment: Well $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ is contained in $\mathcal{D}$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the inclusion you have included, introduction of the Hahn-Banach Theorem allows for the extension of linear functionals defined on a subspace (like $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}))$  to the entire space (like $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}))'$) in multiple ways. This theorem underpins the ability to create many distinct distributions from a single function.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate how the Hahn-Banach Theorem allows you to create multiple distributions from a single function?

Comment: In the context of distributions and $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, consider a situation where you start with a linear functional defined on a smaller subspace of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. The Hahn-Banach Theorem guarantees that you can extend this functional to a distribution acting on the entire space of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. While the theorem assures the existence of an extension, it doesn't ensure uniqueness. This non-uniqueness is where the possibility of creating multiple distributions from a single function or scenario arises.

Comment: So would it be more correct to say that the space of distributions *might* be much larger than $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: In this question, yes.